# Jupyter notebook is querying cassandra on linux and the output has timestamp utc and not cst

Tags: cassandra, jupyter-notebook, timestamp, unix-timestamp, utc

Timestamp while writing data in cassandra : 2020-05-12 09:33:01
Timestamp while reading data in jupyter notebook : 2020-05-12 14:33:01

Answer (score 0):

The `timestamp` is almost always in UTC unless you're explicitly inserting the data with a timezone suffix.

The `timestamp` is encoded in microseconds since Unix epoch. It is recommended to store data in UTC and make the clients convert it to a local time when displaying it.

If you update your original question with an example CQL `INSERT` statement that shows how you set the timestamp column, I'd be happy to review it and update my answer. Cheers!